# In Symfony simple console app, how to add services like ORM,ODM, MailSender

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I want to have my services like ORM,ODM, MailSender and etc... in my console app in symfony.

I used this tutorial :

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/commands_as_services.html

But I have an error.

```
vagrant@vagrant-debian-wheezy:~/www/aaaa/jocker$ php app/console      
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]                                  
  The service "app.command.greet_command" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "command.default_name".
```

Question is:

1. How can I have console app with all services set in symfony app (HTTP based symfony application using MVC)
2. Is it possible to run an action using php cli in symfony?

Simple and powerful usage of console and HTTP using same pattern with different environment.

> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

Comment: Yes and yes.  For some reason you are trying to inject the parameter command.default_name without defining it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need to define your command as a service just to obtain other services - you simply need to [ensure your command is derived from `ContainerAwareCommand`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container)

That may resolve your missing parameter exception. If not, note that `app/console` will [normally try to use a 'dev' environment](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html) unless overrriden with an environment variable, so make sure whatever parameters are loaded by dev include the missing `command.default_name` parameter

It's also possible to [set parameters through environment variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html), in this case, you could set `SYMFONY__COMMAND__DEFAULT_NAME` to provide that parameter value.

As for calling a controller action from a console command, what you could do there is make that action a service you can call from both a HTTP based controller and a CLI console command.